# How to make a tiled background on a canvas in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The following code snippet gives me one image, but I would like to somehow make it so that the image would repeat in a grid format based on the number of columns I defined. How would I do this using a for loop?

```
canvas = Canvas(row, width = ncols*square_width, height = ncols*square_height,
    bg = bg_color, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = im_Empty, anchor = 'nw')
canvas.update()
canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just creating a frame and then placing these canvases on the frame using the built in grid(), below is a working example of a program that creates a 5 by 5 grid of canvases using your canvas creating function (with some changes):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def createCanvas(frame,nrow,ncolumn):
    ncols = 5
    square_width = 5
    square_height = 5
    bg_color = "red"
    im_Empty = tk.PhotoImage(file="gifsample.gif")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width = ncols*square_width, height = ncols*square_height, \ 
                        bg = bg_color, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = im_Empty, anchor = 'nw')
    canvas.update()
    canvas.grid(row = nrow, column = ncolumn, sticky = "nsew")
    return canvas

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvases = dict()
columns = 5
rows = 6
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        canvases[str(i)+","+str(j)] = createCanvas(frame,i,j)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
        print(canvases)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I created a dictionary as a container for these gridded canvases, since you may want to keep the references stored, but technically speaking you can just create the canvases without the dict as well.

Also, for me the image did not show up, but I'll leave debugging that to you, since it wasn't really what you were asking.